# Does romancing a different character in Mass Effect 2 change anything in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-series

In Mass Effect 1 I romanced Liara, I continued my save into mass Effect 2 and she is not available to romance because she is part of a DLC I am not going to buy/play.

If I romance someone else will this affect my options in Mass Effect 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Romancing different characters in each game does have an effect on the rest of the series.

Liara is a great example because if you romance someone else in Mass Effect 2 she will have specific dialogue in Mass Effect 3 reflecting this.  However it is still possible to romance her in Mass Effect 3 even if there was someone in between.

This is applicable to all characters you can romance between multiple games.

Comment: Can confirm. In my case, I romanced Ashley in ME1, then Miranda in ME2, and in ME3 Ashley was really upset about my relationships with Miranda.

Comment: @lentinant The same thing happens with Liara and Miranda.